# Convert Switch case to Annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I have an input json.

Sample JSON1:

```
{id:1, type: 1, name: abc, phone: 11111111}
```

Sample JSON2:

```
{id: 1, type: 2, email: abc.xyzzzz@vmdkn.com}
```

SO the current flow is this json will be parsed and we will check the json.getType()

```
switch(json.getType())

case "phonenumberupdate":
  PhoneNumberUpdate c1=new PhoneNumberUpdate();
  c1.doSomething();
  break;
case "emailupdate":
  EmailUpdate c2=new EmailUpdate();
  c2.doSomething();
  break;
```

Based on same parameter which will be present in all json we are redirecting that json to a particular class and extracting the parameters from JSON and doing the required operations in the files.

Requirement: Handle the mapping of type to class in external file(properties file) and redirect the event to that class directly....
This can be done through reflections?

Is it possible to achieve the above mentioned functionality  using java annotations(am new to using java annotations)

Comment: would u please tell us what `type` Key contains actually?
is it a json type flag or any other info?

Comment: in actual scenario it would be a string with some example: in case1 it would come as type:"phonenumberupdate" in case2 : type:"emailupdate"

Comment: I think get all keys length and pass it in switch and switch will excute ur method accordingly..  This possible way what i can find by reviewing your question.

Comment: Its already present in that way...can we use annotations(run time) directly to map that json to that file directly instead of Switchcase?

Comment: write two pojo class which contains variables same name as  `json `  keys have. and use objectmapper ..

Comment: If you use Jackson, you can try `@JsonSubTypes` and `@JsonTypeId` annotations.

Comment: @Ken Bekov..Is there any reference about the usage and examples?